# I need a specific function F that give Fx=0 if x=(0or1) >Fx=1 if x=(2or3) > Fx=2 if x=(4or5) > and so on..

Tags: functions

As  writen on the title, i'm seeking to make a specific function that would have depending on the x value the following results:

```
 if *x=0 then F(x)=0   F∈N
    *x=1 >    F(x)=0
    *x=2 >    F(x)=1
    *x=3 >    F(x)=1
    *x=4 >    F(x)=2
       5           2
       6           3
     .
     and so on
```

I thought about it for hours and didn't find anything, i ignore if it's even possible, so here i am asking :)

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a integer part of division x by 2. [0/2] = 0; [1/2] = [0.5] = 0;
[2/2] = [1] = 1 , ... so on. Have a nice day!

Answer (score -1):

I finally setteled with this:

```
  F(x)=((2x-1-(-1)^(x+1)))/4
```

P.S: Sorry i couldn't figure out on how to write it better

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).